# How to understand and avoid this tex conflict?

Tags: r, latex, knitr

I just found and started using a package called `condformat` in R.

When I knit the below code as-is, I get: `"LaTeX Error: Option clash for package xcolor."`.

After a bunch of trial/error and googling, I found that this is a conflict with trying to open a LaTex package twice with different options each time (see accepted answer, [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83101/option-clash-for-package-xcolor)). As such, if I remove the `\markasdraft`, and edit YAML to remove everything after `pdf_document`, it runs fine.

Interestingly, if you leave the `\markasdraft` and YAML alone, but change the `echo=FALSE` to `echo=TRUE`, it will knit properly as well.

**My questions are:**

1. Is there a way to get this to run with my draft watermark, and all chunks set with `echo=FALSE`? I'm assuming it would require figuring out which LaTex package and options are clashing, and then, loading that option in the `header2.tex` file?
2. I understand why the `header2.tex` file is causing a problem, but why would setting `echo=TRUE` cause it to run, even with the header still in place?

**condform_test.rmd**

````
---
title: "condformat_test"
author: "John"
date: "Dec 24, 2016"
output:
  pdf_document:
    includes:
      in_header: ../TEX/header2.tex
---

\markasdraft

```{r setup_chunk, include=FALSE}
library(condformat)
library(knitr)

knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo=FALSE) 

```

```{r condformat_test}

condformat(iris[c(1:5,70:75, 120:125),]) +
  rule_fill_gradient2(Petal.Length)
```
````

**header2.tex**

```
\usepackage{eso-pic,graphicx,transparent}

\newcommand{\markasdraft}{ 
    \AddToShipoutPictureFG{
        \AtPageCenter{% or \AtTextCenter
            \makebox[0pt]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{45}{%
                \scalebox{15}{\texttransparent{0.05}{DRAFT}}%
            }       
            }
        }
    }
}
```